# Shared online contact management/address book solution for info on friends and relatives

Tags: contact-manager

Before my wedding, I created a Google Sheets spreadsheet with names and addresses of the invitees.  My wife and I have continued to use that spreadsheet since then when we want to write letters, send Christmas cards, etc, as it has all the necessary info for that.  Is there a better solution for managing these shared contacts?

## Requirements

- Online
- Shared (both my wife and I should be able to access it)
- Private (nobody else should be able to access it)
- Store contact name, phone number, physical address
- Associate related contacts (e.g. husband and wife who live at same address)
- Accessible via Mac or Windows (ideal would be an online browser-based app)

## Nice To Have

- iPhone app
- A way of tagging people as e.g. being on the Christmas card list, being my relative vs. hers, etc.
- Additional metadata (e.g. how are they related to us)
- The ability to export the data
- Ideally it would be free or inexpensive

## Non-goals

- Integration with phone contacts, email account, social media account

I can continue using the Google Sheets spreadsheet if there's nothing better that meets these criteria.  I was just wondering if there were any applications more tailored to this than a general purpose spreadsheet.

Comment: Is self-hosting an option? What is your price margin, in case it comes to paid solutions, and would a subscription model be acceptable? Not that I had a solution ("associate related contacts" is the show-stopper for me), but it would help others who might have a solution in mind.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an open source system for personal relationship management called [Monica](https://monicahq.com/) (like CRM but for friends). It has all needed features you described. You can use it as a SaaS or a self-hosted solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have a software/app solution for you. It checks almost all your boxes:

- online,
- shared,
- private,
- can store almost any type of data you want. In fact, you yourself can determine what data/information you want your app to have, how the data should be organized/connected to each other. You can link two people living together if you want to, create a dropdown for indicating whose relatives they are, whether they are on your Christmas list, etc.,
- browser-based,
- you can import/export the data,
- I would guess by the use you are envisioning it would be free (definitely rather inexpensive).

It is an online platform, [Simitless](https://www.simitless.com/), for designing your custom information system.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand. Just get in touch.

(If you want to quickly try it out, there is a template for contact management that I have made from what you have described that you would like to track, it is viewable right [here](https://simitless.com/en/templates?preview=templates-family-address-book&utm_source=stackexchange). Click the "eye" icon to preview the template with "dummy data". And, since it is just a template, you can take it as a basis and modify it to your heart's desire.) It might be just what you are looking for. And let me know how it goes, if you decide to give it a go.

Comment: Looks like you guys have pivoted into something more general?